# pandas numpy complex if

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to add a column to pandas dataframe with such conditions:
if amount sold(stored in dataset['sum']) is between 4 and 16 prediction should be 1, else round to int average amount sold(stored in dataset['average']).Here is the code:

```
def more_than3_filter(dataset, filename):    
    prediction = []

    for row in dataset['part number']:
        if dataset['sum'] > 3:
            if dataset['sum'] < 16:
                prediction.append(1)
        else:
            prediction.append(round(dataset['average']))
```

I get

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Same with np.where
What should i do?
Thanks

Comment: `dataset['sum'] > 3` is an array of boolean values. Do you want all of them to be true? Or just any of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop is off. You should be iterating over `df.iterrows`, and your `if` conditions should reference `row`, not `dataset`.

That aside, you don't need the loop at all. You can vectorize everything for extra performance using `pd.Series.between` + `np.where`.

```
df['new'] = np.where(
    df['sum'].between(3, 16, inclusive=False), 1, df['average'].round()
)
```

Another solution involves `loc` -

```
df['new'] = 1
m = ~df['sum'].between(3, 16, inclusive=False)
df.loc[m, 'new'] = df.loc[m, 'average'].round()
```

This should be *slightly* more efficient, in that it involves less redundant computation.